# How to get values from url in php

Tags: php

I am tring to send values from one page to others from following url in php

```
result.php?1=C&2=C&3=C
```

But i am not able to access values on second page.

Comment: Read about http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

Comment: what you have tried have you tried $_GET['1'] and so on

Comment: You cannot grab that because variables cannot start with a number. Change that to `a1=C&a2=C` ...

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Erm... Tell that to user574632 and Rakesh... and me.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran That's something new I learned (w.r.t query strings) today and I've been using PHP since the last 2 years.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran those are not variable those are stored as keys of `$_GET` and you can grab them with numbers too.

Comment: And @RahilWazir has got me thinking now. Who is right here? Can we or can we not use numbers as keys in query strings?

Comment: @asprin it's true that variables cannot start with a number, but we're not talking about variables here, we're talking about query string parameters, numbers are perfectly valid

Comment: @billyonecan So `$_GET['1']` should work in OP's case?

Comment: @asprin Ofcourse Yes!

Comment: @asprin yes, that would be fine

Comment: ok..so I learnt and unlearnt something new today xd

Comment: @RahilWazir, Say if `extract($_GET);` was accidentally used, then code will fail. So its always better not to use such thing starting with numbers.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran True. But this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

you can get value from following url result.php?value=1&val=2 using

```
$_GET['value'];
$_GET['val'];
```

Because you cannot assign a variable to start with integer

Answer (score 0):

To receive values across pages we usually use `$_GET['key']`

to receive the values you sent 
just use

```
echo $_GET['1'];
```

so everything before the = sign(LHS) ie is 1,2,3 are the keys in your case and the value would be stored in `$_GET['1']`, `$_GET['2']`, `$_GET['3']`

Answer (score -1):

PHP can access query string parameters with the superglobal array `$_GET`.

For example;

If URL is http://example.com/script.php?var1=hello

```
echo $_GET['var1']; //hello is echoed.
```